# Posting two and more lists in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using asp.net mvc 2 and i found this behavour which i can't understand.
I have following view:

```cs
<%  using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "BlackListGrabber", FormMethod.Post) )
    {           
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedArea, new SelectList(Model.areaList, "value", "text")) %>

<%  if (Model.districtList != null) { %>  
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedDistrict, new SelectList(Model.districtList, "value", "text")) %>
<% } %>

<%  if (Model.townList!= null) { %>  
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedTown, new SelectList(Model.townList, "value", "text")) %>
<% } %>  

<input type="submit" value="post" />
<% } %>
```

and a controller's method like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(BlackListGrabberModel postedModel)
{
    BlackListGrabberModel model = new BlackListGrabberModel(postedModel);            
    return View(model);
}
```

And, last but not least, my model:

```cs
BlackListGrabberModel(BlackListGrabberModel model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.selectedArea))
    {
        areaList = GetRegions();
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.selectedDistrict))
    {
        areaList = model.areaList;
        districtList = GetRegions(model.selectedArea);
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.selectedTown))
    {
        areaList = model.areaList;
        districtList = model.districList;
        districtList = GetRegions(model.selectedDistrict);
    }
}
```

Idea is that then i load page, i see list of all possible areas.(And i see it - it's my first dropdownlistfor) When i select area, after clicking "post" button, i see list of all districts, they loaded from external source and this part works fine.
So i select district from list, and click "post". After thar i see list of all towns located in selected district, but districtList disappears. Then i traced it in my controller, i found that property postedModel.districtList is null. But postedModel.areaList is fine! Does that mean that i can post only one SelectList, or i'm missing something? Can somebody please give me any help?
**P.S.** Properties "selectedArea", "selectedDistrict", "selectedTown" are posted as expected.
**EDIT.** Thanks to everybody, i missed some important things, and you gave me direction to them. 
My problem appeared to be areaList. It was filled by default constructor. I forgot about that, so then i saw postedModel.areaList filled, i thought it was magically posted by asp.net mvc mechanisms, and complained that all other lists are not filled because of some strange glithces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to repopulate your list properties in your model for every request.
The won't get posted back automatically. Just the selected value is posted back and bound to the property in your model (i.e. `selectedArea` is bound but not `areaList`).

Answer (score 1):

The lists should not post, only the values of the select elements in your html form will.  If you need to hold onto the list values, you might try placing them in TempData in you GET for Index, which will keep them for the next request.